# Minimal API NET 7: JSON Web Token (JWT) generation failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, jwt, .net-7.0

I am trying to use the minimal API in NET 7 and failing to generate JWT tokens.

I have collected the following from several sites and youtube videos. Unfortunately I couldn't find a JWT authentication for NET 7 in any post or video, so I had to combine something from NET 6 (maybe that's where the error comes from?).

1. to keep from building the config, I used the new function in NET 7:

> `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer();`

2. in appsettings.json I then added the following:

> ```
> "Jwt": {
>     "Key": "gfdsgf789087fgfdsgfds087807dfgfdsfg",
>     "Issuer": "https://localhost:7285",
>     "Audience": "https://localhost:7285"
>   }
> ```

3. Then I created an endpoint to request the token:

> ```
>     app.MapPost("/security/createToken",
>         [AllowAnonymous] (User user) =>.
>         {
>             if (user.UserName == "user" && user.Password == "123")
>             {
>                 var claims = new[]
>                 {
>                     new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName)
>                 };
>
>                 var token = new JwtSecurityToken
>                 (
>                     issuer: builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
>                     audience: builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
>                     claims: claims,
>                     expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(60),
>                     notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
>                     signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
>                         new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
>                         SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
>                 );
>
>                 var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
>
>                 return Results.Ok(tokenString);
>             }
>             return Results.Unauthorized();
>         });
> ```

4. now when I run the API then I get the token via Swagger. Then if I want to use it on another endpoint:

> ```
> app.MapGet("/secret", 
> [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes =
> JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)] () => $"Hello You. This is asecret!!!");
> ```

...then I get the error message in Swagger:

- Error: response status is 401
- www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature key was not found".

When I look at tokens via jwt.io I get "Invalid Signature".
Under PAYLOAD:DATA I see my data but without KEY !!!!

```
{
  "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier": "user",
  "nbf": 1670946236,
  "exp": 1676130236,
  "iss": "https://localhost:7285",
  "aud": "https://localhost:7285"
}
```

As I see, KEY is not inserted in the token!? I assume that I forgot something, but what?

Can anyone see what the error is and why my token is not valid?

Thanks

Comment: I'd be very worried if the key was inserted in the JWT. The key is used to encode and decode your data to the JWT. So when an attacker would have your key, it would be able to for example insert extra roles, successfully encode it and your application would accept the token. That's not something you want. Handle your key with care and always store it secure, never commit it in your repository.

Comment: Reason why it didn't worked was because you didn't configure the app to be able to validate te token. Generation (as you did in your endpoint) and validation are not the same and are two different sections in your code. Well done on figuring it out yourself!

Answer (score 2):

I have finally deleted the Jwt definition from appsettings.json and filled the options as they were given in NET 6 examples.

> ```
>     builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options =>
>     {
>         options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
>         {
>             ValidateIssuer = true,
>             ValidateAudience = true,
>             ValidateLifetime = true,
>             ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
>             ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:7285",
>             ValidAudience = "https://localhost:7285",
>             IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"))
>         };
>     });
> ```

Now it works.