# How to generate JWT tokens in .NET 7

Tags: c#, jwt, .net-7.0

Since there are some changes in JWT for .NET 7 over the previous versions.
I have a requirement to generate and validate JWT tokens in my .NET 7 API project.
This is done to secure the API access from my WinForms application from where I am accessing the APIs through HTTP Client.

My Program file contains:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

My appsettings.json contains

```
"Authentication": {
    "Schemes": {
      "Bearer": {
        "ValidAudiences": [
          "http://localhost:1851",
          "https://localhost:44328",
          "http://localhost:5078",
          "https://localhost:7134"
        ],
        "ValidIssuer": "dotnet-user-jwts",
      }
    }
  },
```

Above settings was generated in my appsettings.development.json file when I run `dotnet user-jwts` command in my project folder.

My problem is above command generate a local token for development and is working fine. But I need to know how to generate JWT token dynamically though the code in C# and also use it in production?

I have tried following code in my API project:

```
 var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("Name", user.UserName),
                };
 var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_securityKey));
            var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _config["Authentication:Schemes:Bearer:ValidIssuer"],
                audience: _config["Authentication:Schemes:Bearer:ValidAudiences:0"],
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(50),
                signingCredentials: signinCredentials
            );
            var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
```

But token generated through above method gets 401 error on authorization.

I have just remove the entries from appsettings.json file and added them in Progrm.cs as mentioned inhttps://stackoverflow.com/a/74788946 and is now it is working

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = "https://localhost:7134",
        ValidAudience = "https://localhost:7134",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_securityKey))
    };
});
```

Comment: I found https://jwt.io/ very useful when I was working on creating JWTs

Comment: How do you do authentication?

Comment: By adding  [Authorize] attribute over the actions in API controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [Phoesion.DevJwt](https://github.com/Phoesion/Phoesion.DevJwt) for generating/consuming tokens for development and *(system)* testing, **NOT for production**.

1. Install the dotnet tool

```bash
dotnet tool install --global phoesion.devjwt.cli
```

2. Generate token using

```bash
dotnet devjwt create myApi --email user@mail.com
```

3. Configure in `appsetting.Development.json`

```json
"Authentication": {
   "Schemes": {
      "Bearer": {
         "ValidAudience": "myApi",
         "ValidIssuer": "phoesion.devjwt",
         "SigningKeys": [
          {
             "Issuer": "phoesion.devjwt",
             "Value": "c29tZV9kZWZhdWx0X2tleV9mb3JfZGV2cw=="
          }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

You can now use the token for your requests.

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" https://localhost:{port}/secret
```

#### Generating token programmatically

You can generate token programmatically using the `TokenGenerator` like so :

```cs
var token = TokenGenerator.Create(audience, email, username)
                          .ExpiresIn(TimeSpan.FromDays(365))
                          .Build();
```

You can also have a look at the [console app sample project](https://github.com/Phoesion/Phoesion.DevJwt/blob/main/Samples/TokenGeneratorSample/Program.cs#L15)

*Disclosure : I am the developer of this library*